# How to turn an array of numbers into an array of objects, with the number being a property of them?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following doc scheme:

```
{
    "_id": 123123123,
    "linhas": [1,2,3]
}
```

And i want all of them to turn to the following scheme:

```
{
    "_id": 123123123,
    "linhas": [{
        "id":1,
        "duracao": 14
    },{
        "id":2,
        "duracao": 14
    },{
        "id":3,
        "duracao": 14
    }]
}
```

I other words, i want all numbers from the array to turn into ids of objects inside the same array. How can i do that with a mongo query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) method like this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$linhas" }, 
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$_id", 
        "linhas": { 
            "$push": { 
                "id": "$linhas", 
                "duracao": { "$literal": 14 }
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

Which returns:

```js
{ 
        "_id" : 123123123,
        "linhas" : [
                {
                        "id" : 1,
                        "duracao" : 14
                },
                {
                        "id" : 2,
                        "duracao" : 14
                },
                {
                        "id" : 3,
                        "duracao" : 14
                }
        ]
}
```

You need to deconstruct your "linhas" array using the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) operator then [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) your documents by "_id" and use the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push) accumulator operator to return array of subdocuments. Of course the [`$literal`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/#exp._S_literal) operator let you set the value for the new field "duracao".